# Bootstrap footer

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap

Появился небольшой вопрос, связанный с версткой на bootstrap 3.

Мне нужно зафиксировать `div`-блок внизу страницы. Я перепробовал все варианты, которые сам смог найти, но ни один не помог. Дело в том, что фиксация, которая предлагается штатным средством `.navbar .navbar-fixed-bottom`, срабатывает только методом `position: fixed`, и фиксируется независимо от размера страницы. И, из-за этого, при малом разрешении экрана, я получаю, что мой footer заезжает за основной контейнер странички, будучи все так же прикрепленным внизу страницы. То есть это не совсем та фиксация, которую хотелось бы иметь.

Как поступить?

Comment: Никто не запрещает использовать @media

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день!
Думаю, вам помогут эти два примера:

- http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/
- http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

Там совсем не много css-кода и он довольно прозрачный

Comment: да, использовал его, думал не поможет, а потом заметил, что он работает по id элементам, и дает отступ главному блоку. Спасибо, исправил наконец